# How to use preference datastore in Application Class in JetPack Compose Android to Change theme?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, android-jetpack, preferences

I have set up the theme for my android application using jetpack compose. I have declared my variable in the Application class (`TranslateApplication`) as

```
val isDark = mutableStateOf(false)
```

I am using this value in my `MainActivity.kt` Such as

```
  setContent {

        JetnewsTheme(darkTheme = translateApplication.isDark.value) { ......
```

Now I want to get the `isDark` using preference datastore and I have defined the following code.

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class TranslateApplication: Application(){
    val android.content.Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = Constants.SETTINGS)

    val isDark = mutableStateOf(false)


    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        GlobalScope.launch {
            read()
        }
    }

    suspend fun read() {
        val dataStoreKey = booleanPreferencesKey(Constants.THEME)
        val preferences = dataStore.data.first()

        isDark.value =  preferences[dataStoreKey]  ?: false
    }
}
```

first, I am assigning the value to `isDark`  and then using `GlobalScope` in `onCreate` to get `preference datastore` and it doesn't seem to be the best practice to change the theme like this in a jetpack compose.

**My question is that what show be the preferred way to get the Stored Value and change the theme using Application Class in the jetPack Compose.**